# AndroidKeystore NoSuchAlgorithm exception

Tags: android, rsa, keystore, pkcs#1

I am trying to initialize a Cipher object for encryption and decryption.

```
String cipher = privateKey.getAlgorithm() + "/ECB/PKCS1Padding";
        mCipher = Cipher.getInstance(cipher, "AndroidKeyStore");
```

I keep getting the following exception on android:

```
    System.err: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Provider   AndroidKeyStore does not provide RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding
   03-20 00:28:38.270 19817 21488 W System.err:     at javax.crypto.Cipher.getCipher(Cipher.java:357)
   03-20 00:28:38.270 19817 21488 W System.err:     at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:325)
   03-20 00:28:38.271 19817 21488 W System.err:     at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:297)
```

Answer (score 10):

According to Google there is a bug in BouncyCastle that prevented them from installing their provider normally, so they used the provider name `AndroidKeyStoreBCWorkaround` when installing algorithms relating to AndroidKeyStore keys. [See AOSP source here.](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/marshmallow-mr1-release/keystore/java/android/security/keystore/AndroidKeyStoreBCWorkaroundProvider.java)

The following code will run on KitKat through Marshmallow, but I don't recommend it since Google says they will eliminate the work-around when it isn't needed any more:

```
Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding", "AndroidKeyStoreBCWorkaround");
```

Instead use the private key to get the Cipher, the Cipher class will find the correct compatible Cipher:

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
ks.load(null);

KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry keyEntry = 
        (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) ks.getEntry("mykeypair", null);
PrivateKey privKey = keyEntry.getPrivateKey();

Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, privKey);
byte[] cipherText = c.doFinal(clearText, 0, clearText.length);
```

Comment: @DAC84 Ask a new question with logcat, stacktrace and code snippet.